# How to merge two dataframes based on different columns in one dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have two dataframes:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'id1':[3,2,1,4,5],'id2':[8,7,6,9,10]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'id3':[6,2,8,5,4],'Name':['a','b','c','e','d']})
```

**df1**

```
id1   id2
3     8
2     7
1     6
4     9
5     10
```

**df2**

```
id3   Name
6     a
2     b
8     c
5     e
4     d
```

#### Description

- **df1** consists of 2 columns (id1 and id2) which represents unique values for both the columns.
- **df2** consists of 2 columns (id3 and name) which also represents unique values.
- **id3** column of df2 is made up of either of values from df1 rows and its order is also random. Example - Lets take the first value of id3 column which is 6. It is made by picking a random value the third row of df1. Similarly 2 is made from picking random value from second row of df1. and so on..

Now I want to merge these 2 dataframes by id3 of df2 and either of id1 or id2 of df1 based on availability on id3 column. So, the final dataframe would look like this:

```
id1 id2 id3 Name
3   8   8   c
2   7   2   b
1   6   6   a
4   9   4   d
5   10  5   e
```

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Why not add an `id3` column to `df1` using that logic instead of doing it in a separate step? E.g., `df1["id3"] = df1.apply(lambda r: random.choice(r[["id1", "id2"]]), axis=1)` and then assign `df1["name"] = list("abcde")`?

Comment: what would be the expected output for `df1 = pd.DataFrame({'id1':[2,6,3,4,5],'id2':[6,7,8,9,10]})` with `df2` unchanged?

Comment: @ddejohn df1 and df2 dataframes are just a sample from a huge actual dataframes which is already available

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can merge 2 times: first on id1/id3 and next on id2/id3 then join the 2 dataframes:

**Update**

> I want to restore the order of values of df1 in out dataframe as well.

```
out = pd.concat([df1.reset_index().merge(df2, left_on='id1', right_on='id3'),
                 df1.reset_index().merge(df2, left_on='id2', right_on='id3')]) \
        .sort_values('index').drop(columns='index').reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output:

```
>>> out
   id1  id2  id3 Name
0    1    6    6    a
1    2    7    2    b
2    3    8    8    c
3    4    9    4    d
4    5   10    5    e
```

Comment: Instead of sorting by Name column, can you restore the order of values from df1 which automatically order Name as well?

Comment: Like `.sort_values(['id1', 'id2'])`?

Comment: the dataframes values can be any instead of numbers or alphabets. So, it would not be ideal to sort the dataframe based on column values. I want to restore the order of values of `df1` in `out` dataframe as well. I will update my question which might help you understand better

Comment: I updated my answer. I reset the index from `df1` to keep order on merge then sort values from the column `index`